# How do you match a word in an array without case-sensitivity?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I have an array that I will be matching from a textbox

```
string[] streetAbbr = { "Street", "street", "ST","ST.", "St","St.", "sT", "sT.", "st", "st."  };
```

Now, I will be removing those words from a text box when typed using regular expressions.

```
string cleanedStreet = Regex.Replace(txtAddressStreet.Text, "\\b" + string.Join("\\b|\\b", streetAbbr) + "\\b", "");
```

The thing is when matching from `streetAbbr`, it needs to be at its exact case. So, I have put in every case pattern in the array. Is there atleast a string method where it will ignore the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overload of [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f(v=vs.110).aspx) with options:

```
string cleanedStreet = Regex.Replace(txtAddressStreet.Text, "\\b" + string.Join("\\b|\\b", streetAbbr) + "\\b", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

From MSDN:

> Specifies case-insensitive matching. For more information, see the "Case-Insensitive Matching " section in the Regular Expression Options topic.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm looking for. Thanks @Farhan

Comment: Use string.Format instead concat strings

Answer (score 2):

That's just what the [`IgnoreCase` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) is for!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10628110)

Comment: @BhavinSolanki - Yes, I know. I was short of time. :)

Comment: Yes, but you have provide some code as per stack overflow. I think you know that as you said. Your answer was in review for low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Make the words in your array as lowercase, then to compare make text box value .Tolower()

This way you will be comparing everything lowercase

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10628111)

Comment: @BhavinSolanki Why not?

Comment: @Bhavin Solanki, I did not criticize the author, I gave a solution and an improvement since the array may contain only one lower case "street" and not "Street" and "street"

Answer (score 1):

In C# :

```
var stringA = "This Is String WitH Some Cases";
    var stringB = "This is string with some cases";

    // string.Compare method has a third argument named IgnoreCase
    string.Compare(stringA,stringB,true)
```

In Regular Expressions you can ad "i" flag to end of pattern to ignore matching case.

Or simply you can lowercase both and compare.

```
string cleanedStreet = Regex.Replace(txtAddressStreet.Text.ToLower(), "\\b" + string.Join("\\b|\\b", streetAbbr) + "\\b", "");
```